# Strip out comma from position variable

Tags: perl

I have a file:

```
434462PW1       5
76252PPP8       5,714.79
76252PMB2       16,950.17
76252PRC5       25,079.70
76252PNY1       30,324.50
62630WCQ8       1.09
62630WCZ8       1.09
62630WBX4       36,731.90
62630WCQ8       1.07
62630WCZ8       1.07
76252PGB9       1.07
62630WBN6       1.07
62630WBA4       1.07
```

I need the commas stripped out of the second value, and a comma added between the 1st and 2nd values.

```
434462PW1,5
76252PPP8,5714.79
76252PMB2,16950.17
76252PRC5,25079.70
76252PNY1,30324.50
62630WCQ8,1.09
62630WCZ8,1.09
62630WBX4,36731.90
62630WCQ8,1.07
62630WCZ8,1.07
76252PGB9,1.07
62630WBN6,1.07
62630WBA4,1.07
```

Here is the code.  I'm having trouble stripping just the number values.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict ; 
use warnings; 

open my $handle, '<', "foofile";
chomp(my @positionArray = <$handle>); 
foreach my $pos(@positionArray) {
        if ($pos =~ /(\w{9})\s+(.*)/) {
                if ($2=~/,/) {
                my $without = $2=~s/,//g   ;
        print "$1,$without\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since commas only appear in the 2nd column, you can simply delete all commas from each line.  Also, since whitespace only exists between your 2 columns, you can then replace all space with a comma.

```
foreach my $pos (@positionArray) {
    $pos =~ s/,//g;
    $pos =~ s/\s+/,/;
    print "$pos\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way is you can sorted out this issues using `map` function (Input and output `@` array variable).

```
chomp(my @positionArray = <$handle>); 
my @out = map {  $_=~s/\,//g; $_=~s/\s+/,/; $_; }  @positionArray;
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@out;
```

Answer (score -2):

For inexplicable reason you made code more complicated than it may be

```
use strict ; 
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $filename = 'foofile';

open my $fh, '<', $filename
    or die "Couldn't open $filename $!";

my @lines = <$fh>;

close $fh;

chomp @lines;   # snip eol

for (@lines) {
    my($id,$val) = split;
    $val =~ s/,//;        # modifier 'g' might be used if value goes beyond thousands
    say "$id,$val";
}
```

Output

```
434462PW1,5
76252PPP8,5714.79
76252PMB2,16950.17
76252PRC5,25079.70
76252PNY1,30324.50
62630WCQ8,1.09
62630WCZ8,1.09
62630WBX4,36731.90
62630WCQ8,1.07
62630WCZ8,1.07
76252PGB9,1.07
62630WBN6,1.07
62630WBA4,1.07
```